# How to write a Greasemonkey script to handle __doPostBack()

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, dopostback

I'm coming from a scientific computation background and do have some history with some popular and non-popular (ad hoc)  programming languages but I'm completely alien to client side programming and JavaScript.

I've written some trivial JavaScript for my Greasemonkey settings before but that's all.

My question concerns:   http://www.ise.org/sirketler/sirketler.aspx

I'm trying to get all the data about securities and companies from the table given in the URL above which is the site of Turkish İstanbul Stock Exchange.

This data is given within a grid table classified according to the letters which the name of the company begins and at a maximum of 10 rows per grid is given as one can see. Also in the bottom right of the page, there writes how many pages is this info is spread.

For example, you can call from the Firebug console:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$lbtnT','')
```

for getting the companies starting with 'T' and you can browse the tabs of these table by issuing:

```
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$radGridSirketler$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl05','')
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$radGridSirketler$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl07','')
__doPostBack('ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$radGridSirketler$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl09','')
```

etc. for 1st, 2nd and 3rd pages of this table respectively.

I've tried to serialize this by issuing `__doPostBack()` method for a given array of letters and numbers by concatenating them to the fixed string above but it did not succeed.

So how can I use `__doPostBack()` method and append all of these resulting sub tables and get the overall data?

Is there a resource to read for such kind of tasks?

I apologize for my amateur question from all JS hackers.

Comment: So you mean you want the overall data results (eg from multiple pages) to appear on the page as a single table?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And then further access them from my application or save them to disk.

Comment: > *"Further access them"* So you mean you want it to still be sortable?

Comment: Actually it does not much important. It is simply (even dreadfully) adequate to make them appear as a single table as you've suggested before.

Comment: I mean, order by something does not matter.

Comment: To be exact,I just want the resulting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this example will enlighten your path:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Examples : sirketler
// @namespace      http://gm.wesley.eti.br/examples
// @description    Simulation of an aspx PostBack request
// @include        http://www.ise.org/sirketler/sirketler.aspx
// @require        http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/63808.user.js
// @require        http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/89515.user.js
// ==/UserScript==

AspxPostBackRequest({
    "url" : "http://www.ise.org/sirketler/sirketler.aspx",
    "manager" : "ctl00$ScriptManager1",
    "eventTarget" : "ctl00$cphContent$ctl00$lbtnT",
    "callback" : function(xhr)
    {
        var content = document.createElement("div");
        content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText.split("|")[3];

        alert(xpath("./div/table/tbody/tr", content).map(function(row)
        {
            return [].slice.call(row.cells).map(function(col)
            {
                return col.textContent.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, "");
            });
        }).join("\n"));
    }
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for sketching up this but it did not work. I've installed it as a GreaseMonkey user script but nothing changed on that page. Can you explain a bit how to use this script?

Comment: Copy the code and save it as .user.js, then drag and drop the file into firefox. once installed, go to http://www.ise.org/sirketler/sirketler.aspx. an alert window should popup with the resulting data that you want